# How to detect JSON object/JSON Array on XCode using JSON-Framework

Tags: iphone, json, json-framework

I have some problem with JSON parsing. When I hit URL, I've got JSON response like this:

```
//JSON 1
{ "data":
  {"array":
    ["3",
       {"array":
          [
            {"id":"1","message":"Hello","sender":"inot"},
            {"id":"2","message":"World","sender":"inot"},
            {"id":"3","message":"Hi","sender":"marza"}
          ]
        }
     ]
   },
 "message":"MSG0001:Success",
 "status":"OK"
}
```

But if the result of data is just 1, the JSON response is like this:

```
//JSON 2
{ "data":
  {"array":
    ["3",
       {"array":
          {"id":"3","message":"Hi","sender":"marza"}
       }
     ]
   },
 "message":"MSG0001:Success",
 "status":"OK"
}
```

I implement this code to get the id, message and sender value, and work fine on JSON 1, but error on JSON 2. I use JSON-Framework. And the question is how to detect that the JSON response is object ({ }) or array ([ ]) ??

```
// Parse the string into JSON
NSDictionary *json = [myString JSONValue];

// Get all object
NSArray *items = [json valueForKeyPath:@"data.array"];
NSArray *array1 = [[items objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"array"];
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [array1 objectEnumerator];
NSDictionary* item;
while (item = (NSDictionary*)[enumerator nextObject]) {
   NSLog(@"id      = %@",[item objectForKey:@"id"]);
   NSLog(@"message = %@",[item objectForKey:@"message"]);
   NSLog(@"sender  = %@",[item objectForKey:@"sender"]);
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `id` and check if the object that you get is NSArray or NSDictionary like this:

```
id item = [json valueForKeyPath:@"data.array"];
if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    // item is an array
}
else if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // item is a dictionary
}
```